# mvc core, asp-for tag helper issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ViewModel that consist of different objects. On one page I register info about a ticket and I just want to let several objects just pass through to my action, because I need some variables from the objects when I in the action will create the ticket. I also need one object for navigation after adding the ticket.

I tried to pass along the object just by doing this...

```
<input asp-for="@Model.Riksfardtjanst" hidden="hidden" value="@Model.Riksfardtjanst" />
```

and I also tried this approch...

```
<input asp-for="Riksfardtjanst" hidden="hidden" value="@Model.Riksfardtjanst" />
```

None of them work and I believe it's because I use the html input field. Any suggestoins on how I can pass on my viewmodel objects? I prefer not to send them as asp-routes.

Comment: What is the type of `Riksfardtjanst` ? Where are you passing it to  ?  Are you submitting these via a form submit to another action method ? Add the relevant details to the question. You should try to use simple types (int,string,decimal etc) with `asp-for`. Also no need to explicitly set value attribute when using `asp-for`

Comment: You should never set the `value` attribute when using TagHelpers (or `HtmlHelper` methods) - those methods already do that correctly from values in `ModelState`, then `ViewData` and finally your model property)

Comment: `<input asp-for="@Model.Riksfardtjanst" hidden="hidden" />` will work fine assuming `Riksfardtjanst` s a simple property (`string`, `int` etc) so best guess is that its a complex object (you cannot bind a complex object to an input - an input only posts back a single value)

Comment: @Shyju Riksfardtjanst is a complex object so the answer is, like you both say, that i can't bind that to input. I go for databind instead. TY.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke If you post the ViewModel -> ViewData -> Modelproperty solution as answer I will accept it. :)

Comment: @chrillelundmark, Thats not really the answer to your question - its just explaining why you should never set the `value` attribute. And it appears from your other comments that `Riksfardtjanst` is indeed a complex object (and if you insect the html your generating (which will have `value="yourAssembly.Riksfardtjanst"`) you will understand why it does not bind - i.e. you cannot bind that string to a `Riksfardtjanst` object

Comment: But your view model should not even contain that property - there is no point degrading performance by including a whole lot of hidden inputs (you would need one for each property of `Riksfardtjanst`) and sending it to the client and then sending ot all back again unchanged. If you need it in the POST method for some reason, then just get that data again (as you would have in the GET method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok, I missunterstood your answer, I read it like I should use viewdata instead. The thing is I need Riksfardtjanst for creating my ticket (have some properties in that model I need) and i don't want to send them as asp-route parameters. If I just send Riksfardtjanst.Id and then in my action for the ticketing fetch the Riksfardtjanst object, wont that affect performance more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159454/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-chrillelundmark).

Answer (score 0):

When you write `hidden="hidden"` is a typo and it represents `type="hidden"` or are you trying to do anything else?

Anyway, as for your example, `Riksfardtjanst` is an object property from model.

If it was a simple type, the following would do:

```
<input asp-for="Riksfardtjanst" type="hidden" />
```

Since you state that it's an object, you must pass each property of the object as an hidden field, as the following:

```
<input asp-for="Riksfardtjanst.PropA" type="hidden" />
<input asp-for="Riksfardtjanst.PropB" type="hidden" />
<input asp-for="Riksfardtjanst.PropC" type="hidden" />
...
```

Keep in mind that this generally isn't a good practice. All values that originate on client must be validated on server side because they can easily be manipulated.

Let me know if it helped!

Comment: Actually hidden="hidden" works fine (on my other ones that's simple properties). I also tried type="hidden" but it wont make any difference. It's like in the comments under my question, it won't work when its a complex object. Passing each and every object won't be a good solution in this case, for the reason you mention about validation, I have to go with databind instead. TY for clearifying.